# How to customize a container as shown in my image

Tags: flutter

Custom shaped container : -

[image]

I am working with a Flutter application which has an onboarding screen. It contains a special type of pageview indicator as shown in the above image. But, I am unable to create a custom pageview indicator like that. I tried making container curves and its not working properly as my the design. I don't know if there is any package or something which helps me to achieve the same .

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CustomPainter` for that:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: Size(320, 32),
          painter: PageviewIndicator(
            strokeWidth: 10,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageviewIndicator extends CustomPainter {
  final double strokeWidth;

  const PageviewIndicator({
    super.repaint,
    required this.strokeWidth,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final r = strokeWidth;
    final w = size.width, h = size.height;
    final path = Path()..moveTo(r, h - r);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(.5 * w, -h + 3 * r, w - r, h - r);
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.greenAccent
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2 * r
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter _) => false;
}
```